# Howto get new opened tab URL with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, automated-tests, protractor

Hi I'm trying to get the url from a new tab opened after click on a link, and check if I get the expected value. I can't figure out how to do it because I get this error on the chrome execution:

```
Failed: null value in entry: name=null
```

In Firefox the test passes, but the funny part is that it opens a target=_blank in a new window instead of a new tab...

Here is my code:

```
var scrollBar = require("./lib/scroll_bar");

describe("WAM home blog tests", function() {

    var URL = 'http://dev.wam.com.es';

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get(URL);
    });

    it("Should find blog section after scrolling", function() {
        scrollBar.doScroll(0, 1800);
        expect( $("#blog-panel").isPresent() ).toBe(true);
    });

    it("Should redirect to blog after click on link", function() {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        scrollBar.doScroll(0, 1800);
        element.all( by.css('div.blog-post > a') ).first().click();

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            console.log(handles);
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
            var header = element(by.id("header"));
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(header), 15000);
            expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl())
                .toMatch(/^http:\/\/blog.wam.tv\/.*/);
            browser.driver.close();
            browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you see `handles` printed on the console? How many of them do you see? Thanks.

Comment: chrome: [ 'CDwindow-8CDF6C53-A409-41E3-B43A-AB2B52525FF9' ]

firefox:   [ '{bee5199c-4f36-475f-ad40-d5fb304b2920}', 
                '{095648c4-f048-4d22-ae4b-87af1a48df1a}' ]

Why are different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to open the link in a *new browser window* by making a SHIFT+click:

```
var elm = element.all( by.css('div.blog-post > a') ).first();
browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).click().keyUp(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();
```

This helped me before in a similar situation.

Comment: Hi, it almost work. The problem is that it still gets the first window url value. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Termosfera ok, but do you see now 2 handles printed in Chrome?